# Is there a portable way using unix shell commands to tell if there is a configured IPv6 interface?

Tags: shell, unix, ipv6

Specifically I'm looking for a way to tell if the system has a network interface that is configured with a **global** scoped IPv6 address. Loopback and link scoped addresses "don't count".

What I want to achieve is to match whether `getaddrinfo()` will return any IPv6 addresses with the `AI_ADDRCONFIG` hint flag.

I could do this by writing some code which looks up the IPv6 loopback address ("::1") using `getaddrinfo()`. But this is part of the tests for a fairly involved build procedure and it would be much simpler not to have to build an executable just to test this rather simple thing.

The best I've found so far only works for Linux and uses the `ip` command that comes with recent distros.

```
if ip -f inet6 -o addr | cut -f 9 -s -d' ' | grep global > /dev/null ; then
    echo "IPv6 addresses configured continuing"
else
    echo "No global IPv6 addresses configured - skipping test"
    exit 0
fi
```

However this relies on the current format of the output from `ip` which I doubt is guaranteed and doesn't exist on other versions of Unix (e.g. FreeBSD).

I don't think that ifconfig provides a similar enough output across different Unix versions to be of use.

Are there any other tools I'm missing?

Comment: I don't think you can find a tool which is installed everywhere and has a consistent output format. Perhaps you could make a simple Perl or Python script, though.

Comment: You'll definitely have to script this, ifconfig gives reasonably similar results across unix platforms, eg, all ipv6 addresses are started with inet6 <ipv6-addr>.  A bit of Perl should do the job here, of course any ipv6 address that begins with fe80 or fec0 then we just ignore it as it's a link-local/site-local address.

Answer (score 0):

For now, pretty good way to see if you have at least some v6 connectivity is to check for result of

```
ping6 -c 10 ipv6.google.com
```

However it is a kludge. But in a way, it should work on most unices, and possibly more.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really help. Although I'm looking for a globally scoped  IPv6 address this doesn't mean the machine is actually connected to the internet itself. It could be on a self contained test network with global addresses but no connectivity to the outside world.